# Connect two points with fixed longitudinal slope over DEM - QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, network-analyst, connection, points-to-line

Is it possible to connect two points with fixed longitudinal slope over DEM terrain or connect points with maximum longitudinal slope? Make road line between two point, for example 7% or make it with maximum slope, for example 10%?
Maybe somebody have some python code? (Qgis 2.14. essen)
[image]

Comment: Have a look http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189729/faster-way-to-calculate-slope-between-two-points-on-dem-using-arcgis-for-desktop/189748#189748

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood, but I do not need a least cost path.

Comment: Yes you did. What you are talking about is a job for least cost analysis with cost being a function of slope

Comment: I want to design the road in range of longitudinal slope (grade) between 1%-10%.  I dont need cheapest version. I tried with shortest path in ArcGIS, I get the shortest and cheapest results of roads, but I cannot to design road with that results, beacuse too many  broken vertical alignment. Maybe You have an example?

Comment: or something like this;  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131702/connect-two-contour-line-with-calculated-line-lenght

Comment: I withdraw my comments, misunderstood what you are after