# Plotting polyline trail using slope raster with least change in slope and ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, slope, modelling

How do I plot a trail in ArcMap so that it runs from point A to point B?

This is part of a larger model I am working on that takes various variables into account and creates a cost layer that I then can use to run a cost path analysis to determine the "cheapest" path between 2 points. Up until now, slope hasn't been too important. I am just now working with slope in the model, and I am trying to think of a method that would create a preference map of sorts to influence the trail to be plotted perpendicular to the slope. It is fine if the trail has a change in elevation, as that is pretty typical, but I want the slope to influence the trail and cause the generated trail to more closely conform to be perpendicular to the slope.

Comment: If you are seeking ArcPy/Python help then please include a code attempt.

Comment: As of right now, I don't have a code attempt as I don't know how to go about coding this. I asked to see if anyone might have ideas on how this possibly could be done

Comment: Did you see this? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/189729/faster-way-to-calculate-slope-between-two-points-on-dem-using-arcgis-for-desktop/189748#189748

Comment: I hadn't seen that! Thank you! I spent a good couple hours searching around before I asked my question. much appreciated.